# I want to add a row onto a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

The method assigned in the assignment says:

boolean addLineSegment(int [] segment) - add a line segment to the database if its coordinates represent a valid line segment. This should increase the size of the lineSegment array by one and add the given line segment to the end. The method returns true if a line segment was added and false otherwise. The input should be an array of size 4.

I'm kind of stuck because I want to add a row into my array lineSegments[][] without having to reallocate it and erasing the previous contents of the array. How do I keep the contents of the array and add a new row to it so I can add the contents of segment[] to lineSegments[][]?

Comment: I think that's the point of this assignment. I believe you do have to reallocate the array... unless it was explicitly forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java `ArrayUtils` static methods, there are many function that may help you there, like:

Add functions:

```
static int[]    add(int[] array, int element) 
          Copies the given array and adds the given element at the end of the new array.
static int[]    add(int[] array, int index, int element) 
          Inserts the specified element at the specified position in the array.
```

Remove functions:

```
static int[]    remove(int[] array, int index) 
          Removes the element at the specified position from the specified array.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to simulate the action of an `ArrayList`! I'd recommend using an `ArrayList` to manage your list of arrays. If, however, you're only allowed to use an array, I'm afraid that unless you know how many maximum elements you're going to have in your outer array, you'll need to copy the way the `ArrayList` class works(with a few changes), which does indeed involve reallocating the array.

However, have no fear because you can indeed reallocate the array **without** losing the contents of it. In the `Arrays` class, there's a static method called `copyOf()`. This allows you to make a new array of the size you want while retaining the contents of your old array.

Let's have an example:

```
boolean addLineSegment(int[] segment){
    if(segment is not valid)
        return false;

    lineSegments=Arrays.copyOf(lineSegments,lineSegments.length+1);
    lineSegments[lineSegments.length-1]=segment;
    return true;
}
```

This fulfills the requirement of increasing the size of the array by one while still retaining the old elements. For this to work, the array must start out with a size of zero, and it will then grow from then on.

This differs from the way the `ArrayList` class works in that while this one increases by one every time, the `ArrayList` class keeps track of the current index of the last element, and starts with an array of length 10, doubling every time the cap is reached. However, your requirements state that the size must increase by 1 each time so the solution I proposed should work fine.